# how to find an omega-complete non-principal ultrafilter on omega?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, filters

Omega is the set of all natural numbers.Can anyboby give me an exact example of an omega-complete non-principal ultrafilter on omega?(I want an exact example,not just to prove the ultrafilter exist)

Comment: For any non-principal ultrafilter on $\omega$, there is a countable family of elements of the ultrafilter whose intersection is not in the ultrafilter.

Comment: then can you give me an exact example of non-principal ultrafilter on ω,not require ω-complete?

Comment: One cannot. The existence of a non-principal ultrafilter on $\omega$ (or any other set) requires at least a weak version of the Axiom of Choice. In particular, there is no explicit *construction*. As to an $\omega$-complete non-principal ultrafilter, any cardinal that supports such a thing must be extremely large.

Comment: how extremely large?larger than aleph-aleph-0?or aleph-aleph-aleph-....?

Comment: The smallest cardinal $\kappa$ which supports a countably complete nonprincipal ultrafilter is really big. Asking if it's bigger than aleph-aleph-aleph-zero is like asking if the sidereal universe is bigger than a breadbox, only more so. For one thing, there are $\kappa$ many cardinals below $\kappa$; in terms of alephs, $\kappa=\aleph_\kappa$. But that's not even a good start on saying how big $\kappa$ is. (However, $\kappa$ is small potatoes compared to the "large cardinals" that set theory experts talk about.)

Answer (score 7):

An $\omega$-complete usually means closed under finite intersections. And every filter is $\omega$-complete by definition (and if your definition required that it is closed under intersection of *two* sets, then by induction it is closed under all finite intersections).

I'm not quite sure how you can give an explicit example. In details.

1. An ultrafilter on $\omega$ has cardinality of $2^{\aleph_0}$. Writing one explicitly, set by set, not to mention that each set is infinite (since it's non-principal). That's gonna take a long time, and will overcrowd the server hard drives.
2. We prove the existence of non-principal ultrafilters by appealing to Zorn's lemma. This use is fairly essential. It is consistent that the Zorn's lemma fails, and all the ultrafilters on $\omega$ are principal. In that case, you can't quite find such an ultrafilter.

   This means that there's no formula $\varphi(X)$ in the language of set theory such that there is a unique ultrafilter on $\omega$ that $\sf ZFC$ proves $\varphi(X)$ defines.

If you have meant ultrafilter which is closed under countable intersection (which is called $\sigma$-complete, or $\omega_1$-complete), then this is even less possible for two reasons:

1. If $\cal U$ is a non-principal filter on $\omega$, then $\cal U$ includes all the end segments of $\omega$; so if $\cal U$ is closed under countable intersections, it must include their intersection which is the empty set.
2. If you replace $\omega$ by another cardinal, a larger cardinal, then taking $\kappa$ to be the least cardinal on which there is a $\sigma$-complete ultrafilter, we can actually show that:

   1. There is an ultrafilter which is in fact $\kappa$-complete on $\kappa$.
   2. The existence of this $\kappa$ allows us to prove the consistency of $\sf ZFC$, and much, *much*, **so much** more than just that. Which means, however, that $\sf ZFC$ cannot prove its existence.

   But we have yet to find a contradiction in the theory which includes $\sf ZFC$ and the axiom that such a cardinal exists. So while we cannot prove their existence from the axioms of $\sf ZFC$, we have yet to disproved them either.

Answer (score 3):

A filter is said to be $\kappa$-complete if it's closed under intersections of **fewer** than $\kappa$ sets. This notion is normally used when $\kappa$ is an uncountable regular cardinal. "$\omega$-complete filter" is redundant, because closure under finite intersections is part of the definition of a filter. So **every** ultrafilter on $\omega$ is $\omega$-complete; however, it is not possible to give an explicit example of a nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\omega$.

Perhaps you meant "closed under countable intersections". An ultrafilter which is closed under countable intersections is said to be $\omega_1$-complete, or $\sigma$-complete, or countably complete. The only $\sigma$-complete ultrafilters on $\omega$ are the principal ultrafilters.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: I just came across *Models and Ultraproducts: An Introduction* published in 2006 that use "ω-complete" to mean what bof calls countably-complete, namely that the filter is closed under countable intersection. (See https://books.google.com.sg/books?id=VWFL8uUa6iYC&lpg=PA134&ots=lyBFGQ5Lv4&pg=PA134#v=onepage&q&f=false.) So it's really not clear what the notation in the question was intended to mean.